# jquery detect direction of scroll event up/down and bottom and store it to use outside of scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I have the following function which I tried to make for detecting if the scroll event is up or down. It works fine but I also wanted to check if the user has reached the bottom to perform some actions. Or even better, I wanted to replace the down event with the bottom check. In simple words, it should always detect scroll up but should only detect bottom once the scrollbar reaches the bottom and not when scrolling down. Lastly, I want to store this in the variable `scroll` and use it later outside of the `$().scroll()` event. However, when I do `console.log(scroll)` outside of the scroll event it updates only once during the page load and never returns updated value on scroll. If I place this inside of the scroll event then it updates properly. But I need to use it outside of the scroll event and therefore it is mandatory that I can get the updated value of `scroll` variable.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0,
  delta = 5,
  scroll = '';

$('.chat-box').scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
    return;
  }

  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    scroll = 'down';
  } else {
    scroll = 'up';
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;

  console.log(scroll); // RETURNS UPDATED VALUE PROPERLY AS SCROLL EVENT TRIGGERS IT
});

console.log(scroll); // DOESN'T RETURN UPDATED VALUE
```

Expectations: How can I get the following?

1. Detect when the scrollbar hits the bottom and update the `scroll` variable with value `bottom`.
2. Store the updated value in the `scroll` variable to use it outside of the scope of `$('.chat-box').scroll(function (event)` event.

Answer (score 0):

The console statement in the last line is executed after the script is loaded. At this time the var `scroll` is an empty string. After that the last line will not be executed again.

If you call the console statement after scrolling again, maybe in a function or another event handler, the updated value is loged. You could for example call that statement in a `click` event handler:

```js
$('.chat-box').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click: ' + scroll); // DOES NOW RETURN THE UPDATED VALUE
});
```

**Working example:**

(i changed the selected element for the scroll event to `$(window)` for demonstration)

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0,
  delta = 5,
  scroll = '';

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
    return;
  }

  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    scroll = 'down';
  } else {
    scroll = 'up';
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;

  console.log('scroll: ' + scroll); // RETURNS UPDATED VALUE PROPERLY AS SCROLL EVENT TRIGGERS IT
});

$('.chat-box').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click: ' + scroll); // DOES NOW RETURN THE UPDATED VALUE
});
```

```css
.chat-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chat-box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically I just didn't had any idea that calling it from another event handler will trigger the updated value. I hope this works under Ratchet Websocket's `conn.onMessage()` feature.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it should be more clear, what i mean...